# Grunt doesn't give any output [Ubuntu]

Tags: gruntjs

My grunt doesn't give any output, and I just installed all the system, NPM and grunt-cli. When I type "grunt -v" nothing is returned.
This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-yui-compressor": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.7.0"
  }
}
```

And my Gruntfile.coffee is:

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->

  # Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json")

    coffee:
      glob_to_multiple:
        expand: true
        flatten: true
        src: ['assets/javascripts/source/*.coffee']
        dest: 'assets/javascripts/build/'
        ext: '.js'

    compass:
      dev:
        options:
          config: 'config.rb'

    cssmin:
      add_banner:
        options:
          banner: '/* Compilado em ' + grunt.template.today('dd/mm/yyyy') + ' */'
        files:
          'assets/styles/build/site.min.css': ['assets/styles/build/site.css']
          'assets/styles/build/site-ie7.min.css': ['assets/styles/build/site-ie7.css']

    uglify:
      dev:
        files:
          'assets/javascripts/build/scripts.min.js':[
            'assets/javascripts/build/scripts.js'
            'assets/javascripts/build/zt-validator.js'
            'assets/javascripts/build/jquery-zt.js'
          ]
      dist:
        files:
          'assets/javascripts/build/scripts-full.min.js':[
            'assets/javascripts/build/scripts.js'
            'assets/javascripts/build/zt-validator.js'
            'assets/javascripts/build/jquery-zt.js'
            'assets/javascripts/build/site.js'
          ]

    watch:
      options: { spawn: false }
      coffee:
        files: ["assets/javascripts/source/*.coffee"]
        tasks: ["coffee","uglify"]
      compass:
        files: ["assets/styles/**/*.sass","assets/styles/**/*.scss"]
        tasks: ["compass","cssmin"]


  grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-coffee"
  grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-watch"
  grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-compass"
  grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-cssmin"
  grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-uglify"

  # Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask "default", ["coffee", "compass"]
```

I don't know how to debug it.

Comment: `grunt -v` will run the default task in verbose mode.  So what's the default task in your `Gruntfile.js`?

Comment: "grunt -v" in my MacBook show me the version

Comment: OK.  `grunt -V` with an upper case 'V' shows the version while lower case 'v' sets verbose mode...either way, is the problem that `grunt` isn't taking any action?  Or just that it isn't printing the version?

Comment: You are right about -v. The problem is the grunt-cli doesn't work, and doesn't show any output even when I try to get its version.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try removing the package "node". It's not related to NodeJS and removing it resolved the problem for me.

You can accomplish this by running `sudo apt-get remove node` and reinstall  `nodejs-legacy` with `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`

Comment: For me it was 'sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy'  (only 2 letters but hey)

Comment: In my case doing both (removing node + installing legacy) was necessary to get grunt working.

Comment: For those that this answer was not 100% clear: `sudo apt-get remove node` and `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`

Answer (score 8):

I had to install 'node-legacy' on Ubuntu 13.10 in order to get 'grunt' working. Just installing 'node' was not enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't on the latest version of `grunt-cli`, upgrade it.

You might be getting caught by the problem [this update](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/commit/ecc1cb3bf79347c6a35bd480d8d4d3b4016ed779) fixed and that likely explains the different results you and I are getting with the switches.

Comment: We have the last version of grunt-cli, and the last version of NPM. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Assuming `grunt-cli` is installed globally, based upon your `package.json`, do other globally installed modules work?  Did your PATH change recently?  Did you install `grunt-cli` with a different user?

Comment: The PATH is correct, see it: /home/denys/.wp-cli/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/denys/npm:/home/denys/npm/bin:/home/denys/npm/lib

Comment: CoffeeScript (npm module) is working well. What could be happening to Grunt doesn't return anything ever?

Comment: If you figure it out, I'd be interested to hear what happened...but I don't have any other ideas.  Sorry.